# cross platform GUI programming with python

Tags: android, python, ios, windows-phone

is there a framework that allows cross platform GUI programming on android,windows,mac,IOS.

Currently my main focus is mobile devices

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Kivy](http://www.kivy.org) is the framework that meets your requirements.

Comment: kivy can do gui? I couldn't find any documentation on it when I looked awhile ago

Comment: http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You should definitely check the [Qt framework](http://www.qt.io/%20Qt%20framework). Continuosly growing and it's very robust, very professional with excellent tools like **Qt Designer** (to create your GUIs like in Visual Studio).